# The polarization of the determinant is invariant?

Tags: matrices, determinant, invariant-theory

> Given $n \in \mathbb N$, I am asked to show that there is a multilinear symmetric $\operatorname{GL}_n$-invariant form $\phi : (M_{n \times n})^l \to \mathbb R$ (for some $l \geq 0$) such that $\phi(A,A,...,A) = \det A$ for all $A \in \mathbb M_{n \times n}(R)$.

Using the idea of polarizing an algebraic form, I decided to do the following: by definition, we have
$$
\det(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n A_{i \sigma(i)} 
$$

and therefore we could define $\phi$ with $l=n$, but taking $n$ independent copies of $A$ and adding another permutation into the mix, just like the polarization formula. This gives:
$$
\phi(A^{1},A^2,...,A^n) = \frac 1{n!} \sum_{\pi \in S_n} \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^n A^{\pi(i)}_{i\sigma(i)}
$$

This formula is multilinear, symmetric and $\phi(A,A,..,A) = \det A$. However, I am not quite getting how to prove invariance : $\phi(g^{-1}A^1g, g^{-1}A^2g,...,g^{-1}A^ng) = \phi(A^1,A^2,...,A^n)$ for all $A^i$, $i = 1 \to n$.

While this may not work out, I am inclined to think it does, since I used the definition of polarization to obtain all the conditions, and got the one I need additionally. However, proceeding by simple expansion does not work (creating a bunch of $g^{-1}$ and $g$ indexed terms, and therefore discombobulation), and therefore I need some help on why this is the case.

Comment: Is invariance really required here?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is. You see, when the determinant itself satisfies invariance, I would like to think that such a property can be satisfied by its polarization as well. I was told this is true, so it must be.

Comment: What about taking $\psi(A_1,\dots, A_n) :=\frac1n\big(\phi(A_1,A_2,\dots) +\phi(A_2,A_3,\dots, A_1)+\dots+\phi(A_n,  A_1,\dots) \big) $?

Comment: I am not sure that will be symmetric, but am willing to check. In particular, if one switches $A^2$ and $A^3$ only, say, then what would we do?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: You are on the right track; your $\phi$ is invariant. The easiest way I see to prove this is to show that $\phi\left(A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n\right)$ is the coefficient of $t_1 t_2 \cdots t_n$ in the polynomial $\left(1/n!\right) \det\left(t_1 A_1 + t_2 A_2 + \cdots + t_n A_n\right)$. (This is, of course, the old way to construct polarizations of arbitrary polynomial functions.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg You are right! This way of interpreting the coefficients directly implies invariance, since the determinant is invariant! Thank you for the observation. If you like, you may answer this question with the above comment in order to close it : I will accept it.